# Excel: Combining semi-duplicated records (with different columns)?

Tags: excel

How would I combine records if specified columns are the same?

Here's what I have, and the result I'm looking for:

[image]

Comment: There's no code, this is an excel problem.

Comment: Uh excel doesn't preclude vba. If you only want formula, specify that. Regardless, you still need to show what you've tried.

Comment: See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on forming a "good" question.

Comment: I originally thought this could be done with built-in excel functions such as merge, I searched google for answers but it didn't come up with what I'm looking for. Your response indicates to me that it requires VBA(which I'm unfamiliar with), so that's the answer I'm looking for thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done using array formulas if you don't mind them being big and ugly. This example should do what you're looking for. In case of duplicate entries, it simply takes the last defined value (Prog instead of Programmer for Kevin Moss):

[image: Example Workbook]

Enter the following formula into C11 and D11, then press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER to apply the array formula. You can then copy the formula to the rows below as needed.

=INDEX((IF((((($A11=$A$2:$A$7)+($B11=$B$2:$B$7))=2)+(C$2:C$7<>""))=2,C$2:C$7,"")),MAX(IF((IF((((($A11=$A$2:$A$7)+($B11=$B$2:$B$7))=2)+(C$2:C$7<>""))=2,C$2:C$7,""))<>"",ROW($A$1:$A$6),0)))

This breaks down what's happening a little bit, but admittedly it's still pretty opaque, sorry:

```
=INDEX(
       (IF(  # This IF statement collects all entries in a data field for a given Fname/Lname combination
           (((($A11=$A$2:$A$7) + ($B11=$B$2:$B$7))=2) + (C$2:C$7<>""))=2,    # Checks that First and Last Name Match, and Data field isn't empty
           C$2:C$7,      # Return data field if TRUE
           ""            # Return empty if FALSE
          )),
       MAX(  # Take the highest index number, use it to select a row from the result of the IF statement above
           IF((   # This IF statement returns an index number if the data field isn't empty
               IF(  # This IF statement collects all entries in a data field for a given Fname/Lname combination (copied from above)
                  (((($A11=$A$2:$A$7)+($B11=$B$2:$B$7))=2)+(C$2:C$7<>""))=2,
                  C$2:C$7,
                  "")
              )<>"",           # End of conditional statement
              ROW($A$1:$A$6),  # Value if TRUE (ROW used as an incrementing counter)
              0                # Value if FALSE (0 will be ignored in the MAX function that uses this result)
             )
          )
      )
```

Comment: In the case where Kevin Moss with 2 different occupation descriptions, I'd like to keep "Programmer" and "Prog" as separate records. If he has 2 likes, then I'd like to keep that as separate records as well.

Which I think will make the code look even worse!

Comment: That's quite a bit different than your initial question. At this point, I don't know of a good way to combine multiple results into a single result like you're asking. Since I answered your question, would you mind accepting it? Someone might be able to help with your latest question if you could post a more detailed example with the expected output.